# Is there a way to connect ASP.NET Core Razor Pages Web App to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm new to both Web apps and MySQL, but I'm creating a web app using Razor Pages and I can't figure out how to connect a MySQL database.

All I've found online is either about connecting a Razor pages to SQL or connecting MySQL to a MVC Web app. There was someone asking an almost identical question here 2 years ago, but the only answer given seems to be for connecting MVC to MySQL.

Is there a way to connect a MySQL database to a razor pages web app? Thanks for any help!

Notes: I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and ASP.NET Core 3.1

Comment: Razor, MVC, Entity Framework... it's all ASP.NET-Core, and Razor pages include MVC/Entity components... check this link:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-project-items-mvc.html

Comment: What makes you think that connecting to MySQL is any different depending on the framework?

Comment: Because most of the tutorials to add MySQL to MVC uses the controller classes, which are integrated into the Razor pages, so I don't know how to access them.

Comment: For example, I followed this ( https://medium.com/@balramchavan/setup-entity-framework-core-for-mysql-in-asp-net-core-2-5b40a5a3af94 ) tutorial, but don't know what to do at the end when it says "Accessing DbContext in controller classes"

Comment: @iidrag, you can add ordinary controller classes to you Razor app. Also a Razor page has its own implementation of a controller in the page's model. So "Accessing DbContext in controller classes" you could do in your page model "Get" method when the page loads. Good explanation here - https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/pagemodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, there is no controller class in Razor Pages, we do the logic in the PageModel class. Apart from this, they are almost the same as MVC. You just need to inject the DbContext into the PageModel. Depend on the link you refer, you can change the last part like below:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly IronManContext _context;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IronManContext context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var teams = _context.Teams;
    }

}
```